# Can't find the error...syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to Rails and getting this error:

```
    SyntaxError in RestaurantsController#index
/home/action/workspace/yelp_demo/app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb:40: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

but the error, I think is here:

```
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1775868341330703453_36033920'
```

So here's the application.html.erb code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Yelpdemo</title>
  <%= render 'layouts/bootstrap' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

 </head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= name == "notice" ? "success" : "danger" %> alert-dismissable">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %> 
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my _navbar.html.erb:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "Yelpdemo", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><%= link_to "About", pages_about_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact", pages_contact_path %></li>
  </ul>
  <%= form_tag search_restaurants_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-left" do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
      </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here...but what? TIA for your help!!

Comment: Can you post your _navbar.html.erb code too?  I've seen this when I'm missing an `end`.

Comment: Sure! Here you go - just added it in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra <%end%> in your _navbar.html.erb file.

Comment: ARGH. Yep, that's it. Thank you. I knew I just wasn't seeing it.

Comment: Haha no problem.  Glad I was able to help.  :)